# extraction child text python with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

i'm triying to extract from xml file (GPX) all informations related to the waypoints of my gpx file with lxml library.
there is a subset of my gpx file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx
 version="1.0"
creator="GPSBabel - http://www.gpsbabel.org"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<time>2006-01-23T02:00:28Z</time>
<trk>
  <name>08-JAN-06 02</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="-33.903422356" lon="151.175565720">
  <ele>19.844360</ele>
<time>2006-01-08T06:45:07Z</time>
</trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

i can get point latitude and longitude by:

```
node.get("lon") and node.get("lat")
```

but when i  try to get time with :

```
for element in root:
    if element.tag=="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0}time":
       time=str(element.text)
```

i get finally for example this kind of results

```
(1.45,32.12,'')
```

a blank value for time  how can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is a `</trk>` and a `</trkseg>` tag that's supposed to be at the end of what you posted, or else this would be kind of malformed.

I'm going to write this out in a very verbose way. First, let's assume you've got an lxml object containing your xml-- we'll call it `tree`.

First define your namespace, if necessary:

```
ns = {'gpx': 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0'}
```

I like using XPath queries. If you try a query like `tree.xpath('//trk')` and get an undefined namespace error, try again by specifying a namespace argument-- you have to prefix your xpath expressions with the key, like `tree.xpath('//gpx:trk', namespaces=ns)`

Now you want to get a list of all your `trk` objects:

```
trk_objects = tree.xpath('//gpx:trk', namespaces=ns)
```

This will return a list of them or an empty list if there are no `trk` tags.

Then you want to iterate through them (I'm assuming there's only one `trkseg` tag per `trk` tag, and that you need to use the name space):

```
for trk in trk_objects:
    # xpath queries aways return a list of objects
    lat_objects = trk.xpath('./gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt/@lat', namespaces=ns)

    if lat_objects:
        lat = lat_objects[0].text

    lon_objects = trk.xpath('./gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt/@lon', namespace=ns)
    if lon_objects:
        lon = lon_objects[0].text

    time_objects = trk.xpath('./gpx:trkseg/gpx:time', namespace=ns)
    if time_objects:
        time = time_objects[0].text
```